# disable .php and .html files from my directory listing?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I disable .php and .html files from my directory listing?

When someone visit my directory

```
http://example.com/dir
```

All other files except `.php` and html should be listed.

Comment: This would be a better question on Server Fault or Webmasters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your .htaccess file

```
   IndexIgnore *.html *.php
```

This tells the Apache web server to list all files except those that end with **.php** and **.html** .

If you want to disable all files and directories form listing ,Add this line to your .htaccess

```
  IndexIgnore *
```

The wildcard '*' means it will not display any files